# Покупки в приложении через Google Play Billing Library

Tags: android

Реализовываю покупку в приложении через `Google Play Billing Library`. Делаю по документации и дошел до места, где получаю доступные покупки. А как реализовать проверку что у пользователя уже есть данный товар и купить его не могу понять. Дальше что нужно сделать?

```
PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
        // To be implemented in a later section.
    }
};

BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
        .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build();

billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
            List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<> ();
            skuList.add("tovar"); //Название покупки

            SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
            params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
            billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                    new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                         List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                            // Process the result.
                            for(SkuDetails s : skuDetailsList) {
                                System.out.println(s.getSku() + " / " + s.getDescription() + " / " + s.getPrice() + " / " + s.getTitle());
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
        // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
        // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
    }
});
```

Comment: Старт оплаты в доке есть: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#launch Также как и проверка наличия уже купленного: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#fetch

Comment: Да, но вот не могу понять как правильно сюда .setSkuDetails(skuDetails) передать skuDetails.

Comment: Вроде бы можно лишь одним способом передать - получив их из `querySkuDetailsAsync`, что у вас уже сделано. Оттуда и вызывайте то что требует skuDetails